# PHP repeatedly updating and inserting into Innodb, update not finding correct records

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am using MySQL with InnoDB plugin version 5.5 running on CentOS 6.6 x64 and PHP 5.5. The isolation level is set to REPEATABLE-READ.

I am ingesting around 40,000 records into one table. If I only import around 500 records, everything works correctly.

Some of these records may have overlapping date time ranges. If they do, then several steps are made in PHP.

To check for overlapping records, a SELECT is done, if that returns empty, I can just insert the new record. If there is a record returned, then the below steps occur.

1. Invalidate the older of the two overlapping records (record A)
2. Copy the non-overlapping section of the older record into a new record (record C) and insert that record
3. Insert the newer of the two overlapping records (record B)

When I run the ingest for the 40,000 record case, I can see overlapping date ranges, meaning that the select query returned nothing, and then caused the special overlap handling to not trigger. Again, in smaller ingest cases all of that logic works fine and I've looked at the same specific overlap date ranges in both cases.

At this point, it seems to me like the insert commit is not being seen in the next loop of the logic when the next select overlap check happens.

I started looking into options with table locking, transactions, and isolation levels, but am not sure what the best approach is there.

Comment: you'd have to show your actual query/php logic. everything inside a transaction that does a read should get the SAME value being read if you're using repeatable read.

Comment: The various queries are purposely not inside of a transaction as they need to be using the latest actual data. I don't want the SAME data being re-read

Comment: if there's no transaction in play, then read-repeatable doesn't really enter in the picture...

Comment: Understood and thanks for clarifying. I'm trying to figure out why the nth iteration in the loop is inserting data and the n+1th loop is not seeing that data. Looking into Locking and Innodb ACID configuration led me to look at isolation (incorrectly).

Comment: MySQL PDO drivers are buggy like that (I've seen weirder things happening). I recommend you use a stored procedure if you can. Or try to  manually start and end a transaction on each iteration instead of relying on autocommit (don't forget to deactivate emulate prepares). Or try to pace the insertion by introducing a small delay between queries.

Comment: I'll try manually starting and committing transactions. Adding even a 1 second delay between inserts won't be feasible as it would introduce an extra 11 hours of processing time...

Comment: I was thinking more of a 50 ms delay. 1 second is huge even considering network operations... Although any delay based solution is an ugly patch. I was wondering... is it always the same entries that you find duplicated on the 40000 set or are they randomly duplicated?

Comment: Duplicated is probably the wrong word, its that their date time ranges overlap. But, yes, it is the same entries. The input data has very few overlapping ranges, but when that 40,000 record input set is used, it fails to detect the overlaps. Which is why I was thinking it has something to do with timing / insert data not being in the working data set before the next loop starts.

Comment: have you considered the database might be caching the query responses? Maybe it's not PDO after all... Try to use SQL_NO_CACHE option in your queries: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html (Inserts should invalidate the cache immediately, but who knows...)

Comment: The database wouldn't be caching the responses. Each query has 2 variables that change at runtime (set by PHP variables). I've added in the 20 ms delay and that did not make any difference. I also tried adding in a transaction around the set of queries (select differences, update overlapping records, insert new records). The transaction change did make the overall function faster, but didn't fix the issue. I'm just reverting to running a cleanup function after the bulk record import...

Comment: Single-threaded?  Or do you have multiple processes doing parts of the 40K?

Comment: It is currently single threaded. I originally had multiple threads but that was complicating the debugging so I've removed that logic while I narrow down on the best way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# For each of the 40K rows:
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
check for overlap (etc) and adjust accordingly
COMMIT;
```

It will take many minutes; is that OK?

It can be done in multiple threads -- this will speed up the total ingestion time.

Comment: I've already tried using transactions around the select, update overlap, and insert statements and it did not fix the issue. I've also tried using multiple threads split out using a grouping key, which did speed up the process, but the issue at hand is the overlap error.

Comment: And you have select ... FOR UPDATE? -- for _all_ the rows you might be changing?